# React chart : prevent chart's canvas scaling with height and width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am using Horizontal Bar from react-chart-js (https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/react16/example/src/charts/HorizontalBar.js) as below,

```
  const data = {
    label: ["graph"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "A",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        data: [50],
      },
      {
        label: "B",
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        data: [10],
      },
    ],
  };

  const chartOptions = {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
          barPercentage: 0.2,
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
          barPercentage: 0.2,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

and

```
<div>
  <HorizontalBar data={data} options={chartOptions}/>
</div>
```

I tried applying height on to div or horizontal bar directly to restrict scaling up of the canvas but it dint solve though. Is it possible to supply height and width to the canvas of chart respectively.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my case, setting
`maintainAspectRatio:false` along with supplying height/width on div

```
<div style={{height:'100px',width:'200px'}}>
<HorizontalBar data={data} options={chartOptions}/>
</div>
```

helped in restricting the canvas's scalability.

Relevant Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#important-note

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `responsive: false` in your options object. That should according to the documentation make so that the canvas doesn't resize (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#configuration-options)

Answer (score 1):

According to version `5.2.0` you can do it in the following way,

```
<HorizontalBar
  style={{
    width: 750,
    height: 400,
  }}
  options={{
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  }}
/>
```